# Rails Paypal API error "Your shopping cart is empty." after I add items to my cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am working with the Paypal API and following along with Railscast #141 Paypal basics. I implemented the code in what I feel is the correct format, and the link to the paypal site is working. However after a user adds items to their cart and then clicks the paypal link the site seems to not notice the items that have been added and the error "Your shopping cart is empty." appears.

Here is my cart's view layout

```
<h2>Your Cart</h2> <table>
    <%= render(cart.line_items) %>
<tr class="total_line">
<td colspan="2">Total</td>

<td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<%= link_to ("paypal checkout"), @cart.paypal_url(parts_url) %>

<%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, method: :get %>
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

and the carts model I have where the paypal_url method is defined

```
def paypal_url(return_url)
  values = {
    :business => '',
    :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :return => return_url,
    :invoice => id
  }
  line_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
    values.merge!({
      "item_name_#{index+1}" => item.part.name,
      "item_number_#{index+1}" => item.part.id,
      "quantity_#{index+1}" => item.quantity
    })
  end
  "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

Any help on how to fix this is appreciated, and feel free to ask for more information if needed.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?